# SEAM Solder @RequestParam in @ViewScoped Bean with AJAX

Tags: java, ajax, jsf-2, deltaspike

I have a `@ViewScoped` `@ManagedBean` with a `@RequestParam` to initialize some stuff in my `@PostConstruct` method.

```
@ManagedBean @ViewScoped
public class MyBean implements Serializable
{
  @javax.inject.Inject
  @org.jboss.solder.servlet.http.RequestParam("id")
  private long id;

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {...}

  ...
}
```

The *id* is injected correctly with calls like `test.jsf?id=1357`, but now I want to add some `p:ajax` stuff in my xhtml page. This works fine if I remove the `@Inject @RequestParam` (and have the hardcoded `id` in `init()`), but if I want to use this injection nothing happens and Firebug gives me this response:

```
<partial-response><error>
  <error-name>class java.lang.IllegalStateException</error-name>
  <error-message><![CDATA[Can not set long field MyBean.id to null value]]></error-message>
</error></partial-response>
```

Changing the type to `private Long id` results in

```
<partial-response><error>
  <error-name>class java.lang.IllegalStateException</error-name>
  <error-message><![CDATA[]]></error-message>
</error></partial-response>
```

How can I use the `@RequestParam` in a `@ViewScoped` Bean?

Comment: I have no idea what Seam Solder is and what it's supposed to do, but you can achieve the same underlying functional requirement with the standard JSF2 `<f:viewParam>` tag.

Comment: Thank you for this workaround, currently I have removed the `@Inject @RequestParam` and use `<f:viewParam>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `id` must be encapsulated in a `javax.enterprise.inject.Instance;` to be used with Seams `RequestParam`.

```
@javax.inject.Inject
@org.jboss.solder.servlet.http.RequestParam("id")
private Instance<Long> id;
```

(In the meantime I switched from `@ManagedBean @ViewScoped` to `@Named @ViewScoped`, but I think this is not relevant to this question)